# Kusto query to get queued events from a table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Can anyone help with constructing a kusto query from the below table data:

| ProcessName | ProcessID | TimeStamp | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 101 | 11:45:06 | Queued |
| xyz | 102 | 11:45:51 | Queued |
| abc | 101 | 11:45:57 | Progress |
| abc | 101 | 11:47:28 | Succeeded |
| abc | 103 | 11:48:51 | Queued |
| abc | 103 | 11:49:57 | Progress |
| abc | 103 | 11:50:28 | Succeeded |

I would like to get the xyz value that is in queued state as a result of the query, the condition is morethan 5m in queued state.

Here is waht I have been trying but no success.

```
let Events = MyLogTable | where ... ;

Events
| where Status == "Queued"
| project ProcessName, ProcessId, StartTime=TimeStamp
| join (Events 
        | where Status !in ("InProgress","Succeeded")
        | project ProcessId) 
    on ProcessId
| where StartTime>ago(5m)
| project ProcessName, ProcessId, StartTime, Status
```

Any help is really appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming there's exactly one record with `Status` == `Queued` per process ID, this could work:

```
let Events = datatable(ProcessName:string, ProcessID:int, TimeStamp:datetime, Status:string)
[
    'abc', 101, datetime(2021-02-02 11:45:06), 'Queued',
    'xyz', 102, datetime(2021-02-02 11:45:51), 'Queued',
    'abc', 101, datetime(2021-02-02 11:45:57), 'Progress',
    'abc', 101, datetime(2021-02-02 11:47:28), 'Succeeded',
    'abc', 103, datetime(2021-02-02 11:48:51), 'Queued',
    'abc', 103, datetime(2021-02-02 11:49:57), 'Progress',
    'abc', 103, datetime(2021-02-02 11:50:28), 'Succeeded',
]
;
Events
| where Status == "Queued" and ago(5m) > TimeStamp
| where ProcessID !in ((
    Events
    | where Status != "Queued"
    | project ProcessID
))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way is **arg_max()** function. It takes the line that maximizes a specified field (the TimeStamp, in this case), so you can get only the last status (the stage) of every ProcessID.

```
let Events = datatable(ProcessName:string, ProcessID:int, TimeStamp:datetime, Status:string)
[
    'abc', 101, datetime(2021-02-02 11:45:06), 'Queued',
    'xyz', 102, datetime(2021-02-02 11:45:51), 'Queued',
    'abc', 101, datetime(2021-02-02 11:45:57), 'Progress',
    'abc', 101, datetime(2021-02-02 11:47:28), 'Succeeded',
    'abc', 103, datetime(2021-02-02 11:48:51), 'Queued',
    'abc', 103, datetime(2021-02-02 11:49:57), 'Progress',
    'abc', 103, datetime(2021-02-02 11:50:28), 'Succeeded',
];
Events
| summarize arg_max(TimeStamp,*) by ProcessID
| where Status == "Queued" and TimeStamp < ago(5m)
```